# Downloading a Cab file using WebClient gives too few bytes

Tags: c#, http, download, webclient

I need to download a Cab file from a Url into a stream.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    byte[] fileContents = client.DownloadData("http://localhost/sites/hfsc/FormServerTemplates/HfscInspectionForm.xsn");
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContents))
    {
        FormTemplate = formExtractor.ExtractFormTemplateComponent(ms, "template.xml");
    }
}
```

This is fairly straight forward, however my cab extractor (CabLib) is throwing an exception that it's not a valid cabinet.

I was previously using a SharePoint call to get the byte stream and that was returning **30942** bytes. The stream I get through that method worked correctly with CabLib. The stream I get with the WebClient returns only **28087** bytes.

I have noticed that the responce header content-type is coming back as **text/html; charset=utf-8**

I'm not too sure why but I think it's what's affecting the data I get back.

Comment: I should probably add that the url shows an extension of xsn. This is still a valid cab file.

Comment: Binary data transmitted as text with a variable length charset... you really are asking for trouble here.

Comment: turns out that my webclient was being redirected to a different url by the server, hence the text/html response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive the problem is that SharePoint is passing the xsn to the Forms Server to render as an info path form in HTML for you. You need to stop this from happening. You can do this by adding some query string parameters to the URL request.

These can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772417.aspx

I suggest you use NoRedirect=true